# QFile.open fails to open a file inside resource qrc

Tags: qt, qt5, qfile, rcc, qt5.9

I have encountered a strange issue where `QFile.open` is unable to open a file which is added in the qrc resource file. My qrc file looks like this

[image]

I'm using following code to read the file theme_normal.qss

```
QFile file(":/styles/theme_normal.qss");

if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    QString style(file.readAll());
    file.close();
}
else
{
    QMessageBox::critical(nullptr, "Error", "Error loading style file: " +  file.errorString());
}
```

I'm getting following error: No such file or directory

Same code (as it is) works fine in Qt 5.7.0. I'm facing above issue with Qt 5.9.2. What could be the reason?

My example project: https://github.com/warunanc/QtFileFromResources

Comment: Do you intend the "/styles" folder name instead of  just "styles"?

Comment: Did you try the alternative syntax (not that it should matter)...  qrc:///styles/theme_normal.qss

Comment: I am using exactly the same approach for loading stylesheets from resource files. I've also moved to Qt 5.9.2 and my files are loaded correctly. So, may I ask you to put the example on GitHub. I will try to compile it as well.

Comment: @RolfWinter yes I tried. Didn't work

Comment: @CodeDreamer yes I intentionally used that. Working fine in Qt 5.7.0

Comment: @scopchanov https://github.com/warunanc/QtFileFromResources

Comment: I've tried it in Qt 5.9.2 and it works correctly.

Comment: I recommend reinstalling Qt.

Comment: I don't get the error either.

Completely unrelated, but anyway: Why do you need to include the qss to the DISTFILES?

Comment: @scopchanov so It compiles into the exe

Comment: It will compile it anyway as you include it in the resources.

Comment: @scopchanov now only I understood your question. I added it for testing purpose, because nothing was working. Yes, including it in qrc file only should be enough

Comment: :) I see. Back to the issue. Did you manage to make it work?

Comment: @scopchanov nope. I gave up. Went back to 5.7.0. Maybe a fresh installation would work.

Answer (score 0):

In my similar case the problem was solved after removing all Qt DLL files from appication dir (system: Windows 10) and copy new DLL files.

I found that in 5.9 there is no more Qt5CLucened.dll for example. Possible problem was in obsolete Qt5CLucened.dll file

Comment: this could well be the reason. I'll try this

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone have similar case.

My environment : ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Qt 5.9.4.

I have tried:

1. reboot system.
2. restart Qt creator
3. clean project, build qmake and rebuild project
4. changed qrc prefix
5. remove qrc's target file and add it again

There are no help.

Finally, I remove the qrc and add a new qrc with same name and same file, and remove old qrc_xxx.cpp and qrc_xxx.o in build folder, it also doesn't help.

But, I **remove the qrc and add a new qrc with different name**, such that, old qrc named res.qrc and new qrc named res1.qrc, then build qmake and build project, it works fine!!!

I don't know why, maybe some old caches? It takes me long times..):

**EDIT:**
I found the reason is that if you use `SUBDIRS` in .pro and have two project have same name qrc, you will get this trouble.